# Apple developer account and upgrading the OS

Tags: upgrade, ios-appstore, developer-program

I run OS 10.5.8 and I need to upgrade it to Snow Leopard or Lion so that I can run GameSalad.

I'll develop an app with GameSalad and upload it to the App Store.

As I understand, I need to pay $99 fee to Apple to upload apps.

Question 1: Is the following link the place I need to register to upload apps: http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/ ?

Question 2: Is the $99 fee at that link the same fee that will enable me to download the latest versions of the Apple OS for free?

Question 3: Since I'm currently running OS 10.5.8, I can't access the app store -- first I need to upgrade my OS. Can I register an account at the above link before I upgrade my OS?

Question 4: With the account above, can I download Snow Leopard with my current OS 10.5.8 ? (Rather than get Snow Leopard on DVD). Bearing in mind I can't access the App Store with my current OS 10.5.8 .

(Or alternatively can I download Lion with that account? -- again bearing in mind I can't access the App Store with my current OS 10.5.8).

Comment: You are getting some good answers, but it really would be best for you to ask two questions. 1) What are the benefits of the Mac Developer program? (answer being access to Mac software for development purposes) You get yearly access to the Mac App store with that purchase. 2) What do I need to develop for iOS version X? Which will get you an answer as to what OS your mac needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: for iOS development that is the place to start.

Q2: No, you will be able to download the latest versions of iOS, including the current beta versions of it. For Mac OSX beta versions you need to register as a Mac Developer at http://developer.apple.com/programs/mac/. With this registration you'll not be able to submit iOS applications though.

Q3: Yes, you can register an account even from a Windows machine.

Q4: See Q2. I don't know if you'll be able to download non-betas with a Mac Developer Program Account. [Apple's page](http://developer.apple.com/programs/mac/software.html) only talks about Pre-release Software, not existing software (besides Xcode).

Lion at the moment is only available through the app store which is only available when you have the Snow Leopard installed. I'd suggest picking up a DVD of Snow Leopard and then update normally to Lion through the App Store.

Answer (score 1):

I have Mac and iOS developer accounts. Here is my best shot…

1. There are different development programs. Mac OS X (Macs), iOS (iPhone/iPad/iPod), and Safari. Each one requires registration and Mac and iOS require $99 each if you want to sell apps in the App Store. The link you provided has a link that will get you started but this [link](http://developer.apple.com/programs/start/standard/) (http://developer.apple.com/programs/start/standard/) is the actual registration link.
2. If you register and pay the $99 annual fee for the Mac developer program then you can download Snow Leopard (10.6) or Lion (10.7). Snow Leopard will be a big download you'll need to burn to a DVD or create a bootable drive to install. Lion gives you a promo code for the Mac App store which requires Snow Leopard (10.6.7?).
3. You'll need to upgrade to Snow Leopard before upgrading to Lion. If you are still on Leopard you'll need to make sure your machine is capable of running Lion.
4. Yes. See above.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different paid developer programs: one for OS X and one for iOS. Each cost $99 and give you access to the latest and beta OSes for the platform for the program you've purchased (i.e., as of July 2011, the Mac Developer Program gives you access to Lion; iOS Developer Program gives you access to iOS 4.3 and iOS 5 beta).

You can register for the developer programs using Leopard, but Xcode 3.2 and 4.0 require Snow Leopard, and app submission requires either of those versions of Xcode.

Rather than registering for the Mac Developer Program, you should just buy a copy of Snow Leopard (and optionally Lion) and develop and submit your iOS app using Xcode 3.2/4.0.